# complex jquery selector : challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, qtip

I've searched among [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for some time now, but can't find any solution to my problem.

I've got an html table filed by a *foreach*. On each line, several links that pop up tooltips. My problem : can't find the right selector.

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($article) :?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="none" style="display:none;">
                <div class="tooltip_1">
                    "The content of my tooltip_1"
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip_2">
                    "The content of my tooltip_2"
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <a href="#" class="link_to_tooltip_1">a link</a>
                <a href="#" class="link_to_tooltip_2">a link</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

To show my tooltip, I use [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/), and it works like this :

```
$('a[class="link_to_tooltip_1"]').qtip({
    content: $('jquery selector'),
    (... other options)
});
```

So basicaly, I would need something like

```
content: $('self.parentNode.parentNode > div[class="none"] > div[class="tooltip_1"]'),
```

in other words :

- start from link "link_to_tooltip_1"
- go back to parent div "cell"
- go back to parent td
- then go to child div "none"
- and finally select child div "tooltip_1"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am wondering if `qtip` can use the title attribute of the anchor as the tool tip? It should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this is "complex" version;
// assumes .cell and .none are nested inside same container, whether <td> or <li> or anything
$(".link_to_tooltip_1").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest(".cell").siblings(".none").find(".tooltip_1"));
    // $(this).qtip({ content: /* use above selector */ });
});

// this is the "not-so-complex" version;
// assumes both items are nested arbitrary level deep inside same <td>
$(".link_to_tooltip_1").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest("td").find(".tooltip_1"));
    // $(this).qtip({ content: /* use above selector */ });
});
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xJsSb/2/)

Comment: note the title of the question is `complex jquery selector : challenge` ;-)

Comment: I've changed my answer a tad bit :)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm not quite sure what this code does. I tried but it didn't work (empty tooltip). Could you explain it a bit : maybe I didn't use it as I was supposed to ^_^

Comment: I've added jsFiddle link in my answer. The answer is essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.link_to_tooltip1').closest('tr').find('.tooltip_1');
```

is probably what you're seeking for ?

Comment: note the title of the question is `complex jquery selector : challenge` ;-)

Comment: Thanks
I tried you solution, and unless I'm doing something wrong, my problem is that it doesn't stop when the first '.tooltip_1' element is found. -> in one tooltip, i've got as many tooltip content as the number of lines in my table (doesn't look like very good english - sorry about that)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the selector you are looking for:

```
"td:has(.cell .link_to_tooltip_1) .none .tooltip_1"
```

Explanations:

You can't go backwards (match an element, and then its parent). However you can select an element and [verify that it contains elements that match an other selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
"td:has(.cell .link_to_tooltip_1)"
```

This selects the parent `<td>` of `.link_to_tooltip_1`. So this does exactly the `.link_to_tooltip_1.parentNode.parentNode` you described.

Then you just have to select `.none .tooltip_1` in the selected `<td>`:

```
"td:has(.cell .link_to_tooltip_1) .none .tooltip_1"
```

So your example code becomes:

```
$('a[class="link_to_tooltip_1"]').qtip({
    content: $("td:has(.cell .link_to_tooltip_1) .none .tooltip_1"),
    (... other options)
});
```

And as you were asking for, this is done with just a jquery selector :-)

Comment: Indeed it works just fine, thank a lot, but one problem remains : this selector selects ALL the 'td' that have "link_to_tooltip_1" elements, therefore all the 'tooltip_1' element contents, and append them to one another. . Isn't there a way to say 
    "td:has(.cell this.link_to_tooltip_1) (...)" ?

Answer (score 1):

why not place your tooltip like this ? :

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($article) :?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">
                <span class="tooltip_1" style="display:none;" >"The content of my tooltip_1"</span><a href="#" class="link_to_tooltip_1">a link</a>
                <span class="tooltip_2" style="display:none;" >"The content of my tooltip_2"</span><a href="#" class="link_to_tooltip_2">a link</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

and

```
$('a[class="link_to_tooltip_1"]').qtip({
    content: $(this).children("span"),
    (... other options)
});
```

**Edit**
I didn't know you can't use $(this). So in this context, you can do :

```
$('a[class="link_to_tooltip_1"]').each(function(){
    var content = $(this).prev("span");
    $(this).qtip({
    content: content,
    (... other options)
});
```

Comment: I just realise it's not semanticaly correct to do this. But you can place your span on the left of your a. And get them with "$(this).prev()"

@user576875 oh well, I didn't know. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

add a class to the elements with tooltips and rel attribute with the target class of element holding data

```
<a href="#" class="iHaveATooltip" rel="tooltip1">link with tooltip yar!</a>
```

then in JS

```
$('a.iHaveATooltip').bind('mouseenter', function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('showingTooltip'); 
}).bind('mouseleave', function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('showingTooltip'); 
}).qtip({
    content: function(){ return $('.' + $('.showingTooltip').attr('rel')).html() },
    (... other options)
});
```

it's the only idea I can come with to cheat the lack of support for generic data referencing based on DOM structure. Though can't promise it will work as I don't know the plugin and don't know if passing function as an argument won't collide with how it's implemented - you might have to change the plugin to allow it to accept function as content parameter.

good bye and good luck,

Tom

Comment: took me quite some time read and try that one (you probably already noticed I'm not that good with JavaScript... ^^), but I think you were right : cannot pass a function as an argument. Tooptip is empty. Thanks for trying =)

Comment: Sorry to hear that - I've just browsed through the source code of the plugin - you'd have to change it a wee bit to make it work but it's definitely doable! :) check for `// Validate provided options` in uncompressed source code - you'd have to change the first `if(typeof options.content ...` to accept function as options.content value